# smtplib of python not working

Tags: python, email, smtplib

Trying to connect to smpt server of gmail but it is giving network unreachable

```
import smtplib
s=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
```

Neither this is working

```
import smtplib
s=smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',587)
```

It is giving following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 311, in connect
self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 286, in _get_socket
return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
raise err
  socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

Comment: what os are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use port **465**. From [Google](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) docs on SMTP configuration;

[image]

```
import smtplib
s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
```

Comment: Working on port number 25, but problem persist in other ports.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) port 587 requires TLS.

Answer (score 0):

For me when i tried in Ubuntu it is working with TLS port. Script is shown here:

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
```

and it is working with SSL port in windows cygwin. Script is shown here:

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because the network had dissallowed opening of sockets, try a different network if possible