# send mail using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, smtplib

**Problem**: when i send mail to user then from user name not seen in to user inbox only show email-id but i need user name of sender

from: demo@gmail.com    ***username: Demo***

To: demotest@gmail.com

#### CODE

```
import smtplib
fromaddr = From
toaddrs  = To
msg = 'Why,Oh why!'
username = From
password = *******
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username, password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify a sender when sending mail with Python (smtplib)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540976/specify-a-sender-when-sending-mail-with-python-smtplib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

fromaddr = 'demo@gmail.com'
toaddrs = 'demotest@gmail.com'

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Link"
msg['From'] = "good morning" #like name
msg['To'] = "GGGGGG"

body = MIMEText("example email body")
msg.attach(body)

username = 'demo@gmail.com'
password = ''
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.googlemail.com', 465)
server.login(username, password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

`smtplib` does not include automatically **any** header, and you need to include a `From:` header, so you have to put one by yourself doing something like:

```
# Add the From: and To: headers at the start!
msg = ("From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\n\r\n"
       % (fromaddr, ", ".join(toaddrs)))
```

As you can se in the [DOCS](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail).

Comment: Okay but the problem is probable with headers, let's keep investigating about it. If you find the solution please let us know

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create the message correctly. I think the most convenient way to do it is using a special object for message. I placed a class which perhaps may help you to send messages in your project.

```
import os
import smtplib

from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart



class EmailSender(object):
    def __init__(self, subject, to, config):
        self.__subject = subject
        self.__to = tuple(to) if hasattr(to, '__iter__') else (to,)

        self.__from = config['user']
        self.__password = config['password']
        self.__server = config['server']
        self.__port = config['port']

        self.__message = MIMEMultipart()
        self.__message['Subject'] = self.__subject
        self.__message['From'] = self.__from
        self.__message['To'] = ', '.join(self.__to)


    def add_text(self, text):
        self.__message.attach(
            MIMEText(text)
        )


    def add_image(self, img_path, name=None):
        if name is None:
            name = os.path.basename(img_path)

        with open(img_path, 'rb') as f:
            img_data = f.read()
            image = MIMEImage(img_data, name=name)
            self.__message.attach(image)


    def send(self):
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.__server, self.__port)
        server.login(self.__from, self.__password)
        server.sendmail(self.__from, self.__to, self.__message.as_string())
        server.close()



sender = EmailSender("My letter", "my_target@email", {
    'user': "from@email",
    'password': "123456",
    'server': "mail.google.com"
    'port': 465
})
sender.add_text("Why,Oh why!")
sender.send()
```

Comment: got the error  like                        Traceback (most recent call last):
  
socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

Comment: Maybe, this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328222/smtplib-of-python-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Or go the easy way, by install [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) and

Given:

```
To = 'someone@gmail.com'
From = 'me@gmail.com'
pwd = '******'
alias = 'someone'
```

Run:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP(From, pwd)
yag.send({To: alias}, 'subject', 'Why,Oh why!')
```

Install might be done by `pip install yagmail`

Comment: Thanks, but not required yagmail LIB